# Mongo partial AND TTL index

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

Is it possible to create a complex index based on both `partialFilterExpression` and `expireAfterSeconds`?
I would like to have a TTL-based clean up, but I also want to perform it only for some records.
I have tried creating such an index with a command:

```
db.expirational.createIndex(
   { created_on : 1 },
   {  expireAfterSeconds : 20, partialFilterExpression: { rating: 2 } }
)
```

My records are like: `db.expirational.insert({ 'name': 'record4', 'rating' : 1, 'created_on' : new Date() })`

TTL part works and cleans up the colelction, but it doesn't care about `partialFilterExpression: { rating: 2 }`.

Is it expected? Is my command incorrect? If not, should we create a feature request? I find such a usecase very useful.

Comment: What specific version of MongoDB are you using (as reported by `db.version()` in the `mongo` shell)?

Comment: OMG, excellent point, @Stennie. I just checked it on my other machine with 3.4 and it works! The one I tried yesterday was 3.0, and it didn't have partialIndex. Thanks, I will add an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will answer it based on @Stennie's comment. I really forgot that the mongo instance I had on that machine is quite old. As it turned out, it was 3.0.6. Partial index was only introduced in 3.2.

I really appreciate mongo's flexibility and tolerance, but sometimes it would be nice if it at least issue a warning when an unrecorgized options are passed.

In any case, my scenario works like a charm on 3.4.5.

Comment: MongoDB 3.4 actually does add [stricter validation of index specifications](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.4-compatibility/#stricter-validation-of-index-specifications) including key patterns and index options. Older releases of MongoDB ignored invalid options.